# ProtocolVersion in the ClientHello message ssl

Tags: c, ssl, structure

[SSL3.0 specification](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-tls-ssl-version3-00)/page22 provides the following structure description:

> The structure of the client hello is as follows.

```
 struct {
     ProtocolVersion client_version;
     Random random;
     SessionID session_id;
     CipherSuite cipher_suites<2..2^16-1>;
     CompressionMethod compression_methods<1..2^8-1>;
 } ClientHello;
```

Well, `Random` structure is described as follows:

```
struct {
       uint32 gmt_unix_time;
       opaque random_bytes[28];
} Random;
```

It's not clear what about the other structures? `ProtocolVersion`, `CipherSuite`, `CompressionMethod`... How should they be defined?

Answer (score 1):

Just look at bit more at the specification and you'll find in 5.2.1:

```
 struct {
     uint8 major, minor;
 } ProtocolVersion;
```

and in other places

```
 uint8 CipherSuite[2];

 enum { null(0), (255) } CompressionMethod;
```

Hint: using some kind of search for words helps a lot. You'll find this facility in the browser and most editors or viewers have this too.

Answer (score 1):

They are **all** defined in RFC 2246 &ff. The document you cited expired nearly 20 years ago.

Comment: @user3663882 But it hasn't expired. The draft you cited is not just nearly 20 years old: it *expired* nearly wo years ago. It is dated November 18, 1996, with the legend 'expire in six months'.